After resubscription in WooCommerce subscription how to fetch the meta data '_subscription_resubscribe'
function action_wcs_create_subscription($subscription) {

    $NewSubscriptionId = $subscription->get_id();
    update_option('NewSubscriptionId',$NewSubscriptionId);
    
    $order = wc_get_order($NewSubscriptionId);
    $cancelledSubscriptionId = $order->get_meta('_subscription_resubscribe');
    update_option('cancelledSubscriptionId',$cancelledSubscriptionId);

}
add_action('wcs_create_subscription', 'action_wcs_create_subscription', 10, 20);

I need to fetch the parent subscription id during resubscription process, I used the above hook, which returns the newly created subscription id, also i need to fetch the meta value of '_subscription_resubscribe', It return null value but there exist a value in DB.
Also i tried the hook woocommerce_subscription_renewal_order_created still not works.
add_action('wcs_create_subscription', 'action_wcs_create_subscription', 10, 20);

and
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_renewal_order_created', 'action_wcs_create_subscription', 10, 20);

I tried the above 2 hooks but '_subscription_resubscribe' always returns null.
$order = wc_get_order($NewSubscriptionId);
$cancelledSubscriptionId = $order->get_meta('_subscription_resubscribe');

Please suggest which hook is suitable to fetch the above meta data.

You say: "also i need to fetch the meta value of '_subscription_resubscribe', It return null value but there exist a value in DB" on what DB table? Is High Performance Orders storage (HPOS) enabled?

Yes the value exist inside order meta table , I suspect the hook i need should be after creation of resubscription.

Updated:
You can try to use the dedicated action hook wcs_resubscribe_order_created like:
add_action('wcs_resubscribe_order_created', 'wcs_resubscribe_order_created_callback', 10, 20);
function action_wcs_create_subscription( $resubscribe_order, $subscription ) {
    $subscriptions_ids = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $resubscribe_order->get_id(), array( 'order_type' => 'any' ) );
    update_option( 'NewSubscriptionId', intval( current($subscriptions_ids) ) );
    update_option( 'cancelledSubscriptionId', intval( $subscription->get_id() ) );
}

Based on your code, it could work…
Not sure that $resubscribe_order->get_meta('_subscription_resubscribe') will give you something.
Note that when using WordPress update_option() each time a resubscription will be made, the data will be overwritten.

Thank you for the response @LoicTheAztec , the above hook not fetching the newly created subscription id

@ManoharSingh I have Updated My code…

Thank you for the response @LoicTheAztec , this hook worked , Using this hook solved the issue am facing "woocommerce_subscription_status_updated"
